# Dropdown Styling - CSS (border around entire area)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Anyone have a clue how to go about coding this type of style. I tried a background top image and the borders for the rest and trying to use z-index(dropdown under the parent nav) but that becomes very messy really fast. I am looking for a clean way of coding this in CSS any ideas would be extraordinarily helpful. Thanks!

[image: CSS dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with some `absolute` positioning, `border` and `:hover`.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    Technology
    <div>
        Extra options
    </div>
</div>​
```

Sample CSS:

```
.top {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    position: relative;
}

.top > div {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px; /* or whatever works for your layout */
    top: 28px; /* or whatever works for your layout */
    z-index: -1;
    display: none;
}

.top:hover {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.top:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

​
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq6kR/) for you with some more styling.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div id="technology">Technology</div>

#technology:hover {
border-top:1px solid blue;
border-left:1px solid blue;
border-right:1px solid blue;
}

#dropdown {
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: That's only half the solution.

Comment: that doesnt work because then the top left border is missing.